# Getting only Bot as member when I try to get members of the channel in discord.js. How do I get all members present in the channel?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const client = new Client({intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    Partials.GuildMember
], partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION', 'GUILD_MEMBER', 'USER'],});

const channel = client.channels.cache.get('#channel_id');
console.log(channel.members);
```

The channel is not populated with members that are present in the channel before bot was created... Even though the required partials are given. Am I missing something ?

I expect to get all the users present in the channel and mention the user in the chat who has a particular role...

I am using discord version 14

Comment: did you enable the intent in the discord developer portal?

Comment: Yes @zmehall I did enable the SERVER MEMBERS INTENT on discord developer portal

Comment: You might have to fetch the members first using `await channel.guild.members.fetch()`. The `get()` method can only retrieve data for members that have already been cached by the bot, which may or may not have happened. Using `fetch()` will force your bot to cache all members in the guild, allowing you to use `.get()`.